# Separación de cadena var en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una consulta, apenas aprendo a usar javascript y necesito separar una cadena:

```
var b = 1°37'238"N;
```

Necesito tomar solo los números pero en variables separadas:

```
var Grados = 1;
var Minutos = 37;
var Segundos = 238;
var direccion = N;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) para ubicar lo que necesitas.

```js
var b = '1°37\'238"N';
console.log(b);

var info = b.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(info);

var Grados = info[0];
var Minutos = info[1];
var Segundos = info[2];
var direccion = b[b.length - 1];
console.log('Grados:' + Grados);
console.log('Minutos: ' + Minutos);
console.log('Segundos: ' + Segundos);
console.log('direccion: ' + direccion);
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match)
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Syntax)